# Nsdictionary Displays data Wrongly

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am getting data from web service, I am putting it to `NSDictionary`, and by using `valueForKey` method, I am binding data into an array, it has 17 elements, but the count dispalys as 1, as the first data have double quotes. Here's the sample code:

```
- (void)BarChartfetchedData:(NSData *)responseData   {

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    BarChartDictionary = [json   objectForKey:@"Report_DashboardDetailProfitBranchResult"];
    NSArray * new = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[BarChartDictionary valueForKey:@"ProfitAmount"],nil];

    NSLog(@"mypieclass.itemArray: %@ ",new);
    NSLog(@"Total: %lu ",(unsigned long)[new count]);
    NSLog(@"BarChartDictionary: %lu ",(unsigned long)[BarChartDictionary count]);
}
```

Need To get total count 17. How to do that, any suggestions will be helpfull.

Comment: you should show us the data.

Comment: This question misses important information. It is about parsing but the data that needs to be parsed is not shown.

Comment: i added nslog image, but without having 10 reputations i cant able to add image.

Comment: 2013-07-15 19:11:45.959 SubhamDashboard[11363:c07] myPieClass.itemArray: ( ( "16291443.69", 6621797, 5692671, 2477348, 2362607, 2281261, 886410, 848799, 762441, 706688, 497076, 492402, 188320, 124595, 96625, 62905, 60200 ) ) 2013-07-15 19:11:45.960 SubhamDashboard[11363:c07] Total: 1

Comment: you should never post textual data as an image. just post the text.

Comment: I think CouchDeveloper has a good answer here.

Comment: and please follow the Obj-C code Styleguide from google: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml

Comment: You have an array of one element, that element being an array of about 17 elements.

Comment: Hint:  When you NSLog an Objective-C object, an NSArray prints as a pair of `()` with the comma-separate elements within.  You have *doubled* `((...))`, meaning that you have an array within an array.

Comment: thank u gys , i got it,  NSArray * new = [BarChartDictionary valueForKey:@"ProfitAmount"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
NSArray * new = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[BarChartDictionary valueForKey:@"ProfitAmount"]]; // if not using ARC you will have to release it.
```

or just

```
NSArray *new = BarChartDictionary[@"ProfitAmount"];
```

---

Sesame Street hand Puppets explanation:

```
(  // <- begin top level array
    ( // <- begin first element in top level array. it is another array, a nested array
        "16291443.69", // <- first element in the nested array
         6621797,      // <- second element in the nested array
         5692671, 
         2477348, 
         2362607, 
         2281261, 
         886410, 
         848799, 
         762441, 
         706688, 
         497076, 
         492402, 
         188320, 
         124595, 
         96625, 
         62905, 
         60200       // <- last element in the nested array
    ) // <- end first element in top level array
) // <- end top level array
```

--> the top level array just has on element. That is another array which has 17 elements.

Comment: It only displays the top value in the array, but i need all the 17 data in the nsarray, so that to display it in the piechart

Comment: Your array just has on top value: another array.

Comment: sorry, i cant get you correct

Comment: Why do you think the count is 1? Because the array has just one element, and that is another array. And that nested array has 17 elements.

Comment: sorry, just a little bit confused

Comment: do u know understand it?

Comment: ya, but how can i get the nested group of arrays, as i declared it only on itemarray

Comment: ya i got, thanks a lot for ur suggestions.  NSArray * new = [BarChartDictionary valueForKey:@"ProfitAmount"];

Comment: Nope, I dont think you got it, as that line you posted should not change anything. `new` will still be an array with on array inside.

Comment: but i got the count 17 in it.

Comment: did u change something else?

Comment: ahh, no. you are right.

Comment: because u used `initWithObjects:` you created an array with an array as first element.

Answer (score 0):

Is the dictionary object being printed correctly with the 17 value in it? If the dictionary itself is correct, you may need to parse the count object in the dictionary differently.

It may be the case that you are printing count with a wrong format, as it will not be really be a long unsigned...since you cast it to long unsigned, the compiler will not display a warning...

Comment: count is not important, just for information i added count, when i add this array to a piechart, it diplays error,                               2013-07-15 19:11:45.959 SubhamDashboard[11363:c07] myPieClass.itemArray: (
        (
        "16291443.69",
        6621797,
        5692671,
        2477348,
        2362607,
        2281261,
        886410,
        848799,
        762441,
        706688,
        497076,
        492402,
        188320,
        124595,
        96625,
        62905,
        60200
    )
) 
2013-07-15 19:11:45.960 SubhamDashboard[11363:c07] Total: 1